# Making a view case insensitive for a case sensitive table

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, case-insensitive

Is is possible to make a view case insensitive if the table (or view) it is looking at is case sensitive?

I have view on a database that looks at a view on another server (that I can't alter) that is case sensitive, and stored in all caps. I want my view to be case insensitive, but I can't find a way to do it. Collate only works on the select statement, because I can't alter the view to add collation. The table's properties show that it's case insensitive, but it isn't.

The results of

```
exec sp_help 'dbo.myView'
```

shows that the collation is case sensitive. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just add `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` to the columns coming from the remote server in your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` to the columns coming from the remote table.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[myView] (
   TextColumn1, 
   Column2, 
   TextColumn3)
AS 

   SELECT 
      t.TextColumn1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
      t.Column2,
      t.TextColumn3 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
   FROM 
      RemoteServer.dbo.REMOTE_TABLE AS t
GO
```

---

**Reference:**

[COLLATE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE tb_CollateTest (str varchar(max))
GO

INSERT tb_CollateTest VALUES
  ('Unique')
 ,('uNiQuE')
GO

CREATE VIEW vw_CollateTest AS
SELECT
  str COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AS str
FROM tb_CollateTest
GROUP BY str COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
GO

SELECT * FROM vw_CollateTest
```

---

```
str
----------
Unique
uNiQuE

(2 row(s) affected)
```